# Use % to shortcut one integer

Tags: solidity

I just saw that we can use % to shorten an integer, but I don't understand how this is possible.

In the example

```
uint dnaDigits = 16; //(uint = insignet int)
uint dnaModulus = 10 ** dnaDigits;
 
return rand % dnaModulus; //with rand = hash256
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The percent sign is a [modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation).

> *modulo operation returns the remainder or signed remainder of a division, after one number is divided by another*

A simple example, where `rand` is 7 and `dnaModulus` is 3... The largest integer (less or equal 7) divisible by 3 (to an integer result) is 6... So that makes the reminder 1 (the difference between 6 and 7).

---

In programming, it's often used to validate whether a number is odd or even.

```
if (number % 2 == 0) {
  // number is even
}
```

or whether it's divisible by 10

```
if (number % 10 == 0) {
  // is 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, ...
}
```

Comment: What you say I understand, but what I don't understand is that my hash doesn't only contain numbers. Here he uses modulo to go from a length of 256 to 16

Comment: Keccak256 returns a large number (256bit) that can be interpreted as 64 hex characters, which is probably the form that you're familiar with. But this number can also be interpreted in the decimal system. So it's just counting with larger numbers than we're used to. But it's still returning the decimal reminder after dividing the decimal interpretation of `rand` (the large 256bit number) by decimal interpretation of `dnaModulus`.